# DAX formula in tabular model showing (blank) when calculating MTD total purchases

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dax

I am writing DAX in a ssas tabular model and running into a problem.

I wish to calculate the total amount purchased MTD.

I have a measure which calculates the total purchased which works fine however when I use the below queries they will not produce the expected result...

```
Total Purchased MTD:= CALCULATE([Total Purchased],DATESMTD('Date'[Date]))
Total Purchased YTD:= CALCULATE([Total Purchased],DATESYTD('Date'[Date]))
```

Total Purchased calculation:

```
Total Purchased:= CALCULATE([Total Orders],'Order'[Is Sale] = TRUE())
```

I have checked and there is an active relationship between the date and order table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Will

Comment: Did you mark your 'Date' table as a Date Table?

Comment: Hi mxix, yes i have marked it as a date table and processed, no change i am afraid

Comment: I would provide some sample data and expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change DATESMTD to this calculation (this is syntax sugar for):

```
DATESBETWEEN ( 
    <Dates>, 
    STARTOFMONTH ( LASTDATE ( <Dates> ) ),
    LASTDATE ( <Dates> ) 
)
```

check what every part of this calculation return for you.